# template for FORM in Symfony with admin generator

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I generated admin doctrine in Symfony 1.4. I use generator.yml. I would like edit template for form. I know that it is in cache. I copy this for backend, but there doesnt have $form.
I would like make somethings as in frontend:

```
<table>
<tr><td>$form['name']->render();</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>$form['city']->render();</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

etc, but how can i make with admin generator? there are many include partial and foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best thing is to customize the generator templates themselves instead of copying from cache and overriding. These templates can be found in symfony_folder/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/data/generator/sfDoctrineModule/admi‌​n/template/templates